# Can I hide the div when you hover over a youtube video?

Tags: css

Im trying to set a div on top of a youtube video and then when you hover over the div the div disappears and you're able to play the youtube video underneath, is this achievable through css only?

```css
#box{
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 560px;
    height: 315px;
    margin-top: -315px;
    z-index: 1;
}  
#box:hover {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
iframe {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qqrvm2XDvpQ" frameborder="0"         allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="box"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g20knmbw/1/

Comment: Short answer... NO. you will be able to hide the div on hover but once the user moves the mouse away from the div the div will re-appear.

Comment: thats fine I got it to the point where it does hide but it stutters and flickers even when the mouse is over the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap everything and then position the overlay div using `position:absolute`...then use the hover on the wrapper to affect the overlay.

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

iframe {
  display:block;
  }
#box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap:hover #box {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qqrvm2XDvpQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/g20knmbw/3/)